# SKPhysicsBody not lining up with SKShapeNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skshapenode

I have a circle node created like so:

```
 let path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 150, width: playerWidth, height: playerHeight), nil)
    self.path = path


    fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Whenever I add a physicsBody (circleOfRadius: CGFloat),  it refuses to match up with the position of the node and ends up near the bottom left of the simulator screen.

Is there a way I can change the position of the physics body? Will post more code if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move physics body do not set the shape's body. Create a SKNode which is attached to the shape, then set the SKNode's physicsBody. To move the body, play around with the position of the SKNode that you created on the shape.

```
 let shape = SKShapeNode(initialize here)
 let bodyNode = SKNode()
 shape.addChild(bodyNode)
 bodyNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(initialize here)

 // To move the body;
 bodyNode.position = CGPoint(point you wish)
```